# Using a docker volume with postgresql to verify it is saving on the hosts filesystem

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to get docker volumes working.

I have defined a volume in my Dockerfile as follows:

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"

  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    #container_name: db
    volumes:
      - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"


volumes:
  db-data:
```

Now my question is, when I do a docker-compose up I don't see my data persisted on my local laptop (or server).

I just want to test/verify that my data is saving to the host's filesystem, so if I start/stop docker when it restarts it reads from the database file on the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That construct saves data in a *named volume*; if you look under `/var/lib/docker/volumes` as root you should be able to see it there (though mucking around in `/var/lib/docker` generally isn't advisable; and I believe this is one of the things where Docker Compose will change the name to try to make it unique).

If you want the data to be saved in a host directory, change the volume declaration to explicitly have a relative or absolute path.  You won't need the explicit volume declaration, and for this you can remove the volumes block entirely.  That would leave you with a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - "./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

Comment: could I define a volume base path and then use that for all my services?

Comment: Relative paths will be relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file; or I believe this is a case where [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) works.